# ViewWillTransitonToSize rotation Animation

Tags: ios, swift, viewwilltransitiontosize

I'm trying to replace the default iOS device rotation animation on my UIcollectionView. 
I'm using viewWillTransitionToSize and the targetTransform() on the transitionCoordinator to prevent the default view rotation, and then use a transform  to rotate each visibleCell into the correct orientation.
It works fine, except:

1. The Cells on the immediate outer bounds of the visible rect are not getting rotated.
2. My logs show that the collectionView.visibleCells() array is giving me what it is supposed to: the visible cells, but I found that if i let the view rotate with the default animation, the visibleCells array gives me the visible Cells PLUS the cells in the immediate neighbourhood.
3. I've been trying to access these "neighbourhood" cells so I can rotate them but all my attempts failed with a bang.

Here’s my implementation of ViewWillTransitionTosize :

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize( size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){
       super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size , withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

      let transf : CGAffineTransform = coordinator.targetTransform()
      let invertedRotation = CGAffineTransformInvert(transf)
      let currentBounds = view.bounds
     coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({
     _ in

     self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(self.view.transform, invertedRotation )
        self.undoRotation =  CGAffineTransformConcat(self.undoRotation, transf)
     self.view.bounds = currentBounds
}, completion: ({ finished in
         if ( finished != nil){

                 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,  animations: {
                 for cell  in self.collectionView!.visibleCells(){
                    cell.contentView.transform = self.undoRotation
                 }
             })}
         })
)
```

Here a quick gif. to ilustrate the problem:  http://www.blessinglopes.com/Info

Any Help will be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: do you have the code uploaded somewhere, so I can try it out to see whats wrong?

Comment: Sorry @rakeshbs, I don't have the code online, but it's a straightforward collectionView using a regular collectionViewFlowLayout. The only custom feature is the rotation animation that is coded in ViewWillTransitionToSize.

Comment: @rakeshbs I'll prepare an example project and put it online

Comment: @rakeshbs Here's a zip with a working Xcode example:  http://files.cargocollective.com/518889/swift-collectionview.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by implementing a separate thread in which the cell is animated. You can check out the code in the git repository below.

https://github.com/rakeshbs/RotatingCollectionView

Comment: it was an interesting challenge :) probably you can speed it up a lot if you try some more. I was in a hurry

Comment: I've checked the performance and it is definitely slower than before. But it works and I really like your approach. I'll do some experiments to try and speed up the process. Again, many thanks! Really Appreciate it.  @rakeshbs

Comment: After looking carefully at your code i found something interesting: You've added the much needed rotating transform to the cell in -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath when it dequeues the cells. Adding This line of code: 

myCell.contentView.transform = self.counterRotation 

and keeping my original implementation of viewWillTransitionToSize is ALL it's needed to fix the problem :) @rakeshbs

Comment: where did you add `myCell.contentView.transform = self.counterRotation ` ? I thought the dequeueing caused the animations to stop midway.

Comment: I think i didn't do it that way because the newly dequeued cells won't animate if u rotate while the tableview is scrolling inertially(swiping and letting go)

Comment: `myCell.contentView.transform = self.counterRotation` is added to the collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: method.
Yes, you're right. The newly dequeue cell doesn't animate alongside the other if the collection view rotates while scrolling. I'll see if i find a way to fix this. I'll report back if I find something new.
Thanks again! You've been a tremendous help. :)

Comment: yeah. this is why i went for the twisted solution. the animation we do through the uiview.animate block gets cancelled when the cell gets dequeued. which does not look good. so i wrote the animation manually.

Comment: yes. sadly :( which was why I was reluctant to post it.

Comment: Yes, you approach looks seamless when the collection view is scrolling while the device rotates - there a performance price involved too. 
On the other hand I like the simplicity of the ViewWillTransitionTosize:withTransitionCoordinator idea and if I find a fix for the dequeue issue it will preform quite fast, i think. @rakeshbs

Comment: lol sorry, i keep pressing the ENTER key before i finish my comment :)

Comment: yes it will. i prefer your method too. except for that limitation. maybe you can find a way to restart the animations for those few cells.

Comment: Think I fix it. I've been relying on the collectionView.visibleCells() array to animate the rotating of each cell. 
What i've done is create a new array that holds not only a copy of the visibleCells(), but also the new cells that get dequeued as we scroll. This new array is what goes into the animation block of ViewWillTransitionToSize. 
When the collectionsView scrolls, the newly dequeue cells pop into the array, get animated on the fly and are then removed, to keep the array from getting too big. This makes for a smooth animation of the cells as they appear on screen.

Answer (score 0):

From cell reuse purpose, `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath` will always be called when you scroll.
So simple make sure all your new appeared cells are applied the correct new orientation. For example add this line `cell.contentView.transform = self.counterRotation` in your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath` after the cell is dequeued.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell : MyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCollectionViewCell
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "MyImg")!
    cell.contentView.transform = self.undoRotation
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I figured out after a few experiments with the example @rakeshbs so kindly provided. Anyway, thx all the same for stopping by  :)

Comment: Great, but there's still a flash of duplicate copy frames in iphone 5, and in iphone 6, I can't see another copy of the cells, but can see the screen's  blinking for 1sec, how did you fix this? what I can imagine is temporarily increase the size of root view, not sure if this would work I haven't got tried.